# Facebook like wall

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to know if someone knows about a already open source api for a facebook like wall?

Comment: What about the Facebook API?  Or perhaps you should be a bit more specific about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a list of recent posts, then you just get the data from the database and display it in a "wall-like" way.